# I am getting "This site can’t be reached" on my browser when I am trying to run my angular project

Tags: angular

I have installed Angular 13 on my system and I am not able to view its output on my chrome or in any browser. Getting "This site can't be reached" error. I am new to angular. Can anyone help me with that one?

```
Angular CLI: 13.3.9
Node: 14.15.0
Package Manager: npm 6.14.8
OS: Linux x64

Angular: 13.3.11
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1303.9
@angular-devkit/build-angular   13.3.9
@angular-devkit/core            13.3.9
@angular-devkit/schematics      13.3.9
@angular/cli                    13.3.9
@schematics/angular             13.3.9
rxjs                            7.5.6
typescript                      4.6.4
```

And the package JSON file is this.

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~13.3.0",
    "@angular/common": "~13.3.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~13.3.0",
    "@angular/core": "~13.3.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~13.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~13.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~13.3.0",
    "@angular/router": "~13.3.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.5.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~13.3.9",
    "@angular/cli": "~13.3.9",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~13.3.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.10.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.7.0",
    "typescript": "~4.6.2"
  }
}
```

And on the browser console, I am getting this warning.

```
crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated.
(anonymous) @ (index):6774
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: could you please share your package.json file?

Comment: What did you do in order to run the application?

Comment: @CarlitosJan Just run the command "ng serve". Also tried the below answer "ng serve --open".

Comment: Did you make any changes to your local hosts file? You could try http://127.0.0.1:4200. Please check the hosts file to see if it has the following entry: "127.0.0.1 localhost"

Comment: @CarlitosJan I didn't make any change in host. I didn't see any file in my project with host name. What is a host file?

Comment: What happens if you open a terminal and type `ping localhost`?

Comment: The file is located under /etc/hosts on Linux

Comment: Can you please share screenshot of browser tab as well?

Comment: @ChristianVincenzoTraina I am getting something like this: ```PING localhost (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.051 ms
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.047 ms```

Comment: It can be anything, maybe the firewall maybe the antivirus. What happens if you type `curl localhost:4200`?

Comment: @ChristianVincenzoTraina Getting this: `curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 4200: Connection refused`

Comment: There is probably a firewall blocking HTTP requests

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to  clear your history, cookies, and cache.
Then delete the `node_modules` folder and run `yarn install` or `npm install` and then run `ng serve --open`. The `--open` option automatically opens your browser to `http://localhost:4200/`.

Comment: Tried didn't work. Getting the same error.

Comment: are you unable to visit the webpage? or is the dev server also unable to start?

Comment: Unable to visit webpage.